# Android. База данных Sugar ORM, можно ли узнать id по значению?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, orm

С помошью Sugar ORM можно получить значение по id

```
Contact title = Contact.findById(Contact.class, 2);
String titleStr = title.title;
```

А можно ли наоборот получить id по значению?

Полность получить все поля можно по значению, таким оброзом

```
List<Contact> authors = Contact.find(Contact.class, "name = ?", "Nathan");
```

Не могу понять, как получить именно id елемента, где значения одного поля например "Nathan"???

Comment: Ну, если вы знаете, что такое значение может быть только одно, то просто берите первый элемент списка и берите его ID

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял. Примерно так и сделал, теперь вроде все заработало как надо)